# Editing sources.list

Tags: software-sources

I have edited the sources.list file in order to install a distribution of ns2. However when I run `sudo apt-get update` command it gives a 404 error that the package could not be located.

looking at the link, it directs to 'binary-i386', however inspecting the link I need it to direct to 'binary-amd64'. How could I change this?

The link in sources.list only contains `/precise contrib` at the end, the binary-i386 is inputted automatically by Ubuntu.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to direct to `binary-amd64`? Have you looked this post: [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/q/65911/62483) Also, you can create a `sources.list` to your needs in [this site](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/).

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply ... when i go to the index in a browser and navigate to the location of the package the link includes the amd64 library not i386, im confused as to why Ubuntu is automatically directing to the wrong directory ... i am using a 64 bit version of Ubuntu also meaning the package should work :/

Comment: Please, add the content of your `sources.list` file into your question. Also, upload the output of `apt-get update` in paste.ubuntu.com and link it here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `apt-get` for installing ns2. The best way is installing it manually, because you can install the most updated version of it. Some months ago I installed `ns2.30 on Ubuntu 12.10`. You can find my experience in my [blog](http://cybera.blog.ir).

Comment: If you want to do it by editing sources.list, tell me I help you.